# Sharekit Facebook in iPhone giving error as Application Error

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I am getting the following error page once I logged in to the facebook in iPhone.
Actually I am using sharekit for facebook connect.

[image: Getting this Error after login in to the facebook]

Please Help me in this.

Thanks
Satya

Comment: Which version of ShareKit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sharekit shows this kind of issues sometimes. Also, the dummy account which you are using to check might have some secure checks resulting in timeout for response. So i would like you to cross-check with another account as well.

Cheers,

Tarun.